# How to organize apps into folders in Show Applications 22.04.1

Tags: 22.04

it must be right in front of me--wondering how to Organize applications into groups. I see a "Utilities" folder. I want to create more folders to group applications by type, for example Audio, Photo, and so on.

Thanks for advice, apologies for such a noob question.

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS jammy

Comment: Resolved by a redditor--it was far simpler than I had been making it:

>
Just drag an application (lets use the calculator for an example) into another application (lets use Firefox or Thunderbird for this example) and voila! It's very similar to how you do it on Android or iOS. Oh, and don't forget to change the name of the folder at the top.
>

Comment: Feel free to write this comment out as a full answer to your own question. This is fully acceptable here, and may help other users.

Answer (score 1):

It was simple, just drag and drop two apps onto each other that you would like to live together.  Though I have not yet figured out how to un-do this.

Resolved by a redditor--it was far simpler than I had been making it: > Just drag an application (lets use the calculator for an example) into another application (lets use Firefox or Thunderbird for this example) and voila! It's very similar to how you do it on Android or iOS. Oh, and don't forget to change the name of the folder at the top. >

> 